# What are .a files in Go?

Tags: go

In the GO standard library, there are source files under my Go installation:

```
C:\Go\src\pkg
```

The packages under the source folder corresponds to .a files in here:

```
C:\Go\pkg\windows_amd64
```

What are the .a files ? What are they used for and how are they generated. I noticed, that they get generated automatically when i do `go get libraryhostedingithub`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

They are compiled packages. It is these files you are referencing when you write `import foo/bar`. It refers to `$GOROOT/pkg/$GOOS_$GOARCH/foo/bar.a` and not `$GOROOT/src/foo/bar/*.go`.

These files contain the compiled package binary code, along with debug symbols and source information.

Comment: Does that mean, that it's possible to distribute libraries in purely compiled package form? I remember reading from somewhere, that it's only possible to distribute libraries in Go via source files.

Comment: In principle, yes you could do that. But remember that they are compiled for specific platforms. So a package for one platform can not be imported successfully into a build cycle, targeted at another platform. In the end, source distribution is much less of a hassle.

Comment: @JohnNevermore Right now, building w/o source is not supported although it should be possible; all the information needed is included in the library file (.a)

Comment: @Dante Yes, of course u can do that. Please check a useful script in https://github.com/YongHaoWu/golang-binary-package-generator .

Answer (score 8):

Go `.a` package object archive files are created by the `go tool pack` command: [Command pack](http://golang.org/cmd/pack/).

Answer (score 7):

According to the [docs](http://godoc.org/go/build):

> If DIR is a directory listed in the Go path, a package with source in DIR/src/foo/bar can be imported as "foo/bar" and has its compiled form installed to "DIR/pkg/GOOS_GOARCH/foo/bar.a" (or, for gccgo, "DIR/pkg/gccgo/foo/libbar.a").

So it seems to be just the compiled/installed package.

Answer (score 6):

As @peterSO said, "Go `.a` package object archive files are created by the `go tool pack` command: [Command pack](http://golang.org/cmd/pack/).".

However, to be even more clear, you can copy these files and rename the extension to `.tar.gz` and open them as a regular compressed tar image in a program like `7zip` or the `tar -xvf` command in `Linux`, or you can use the `go tool pack` which is effectively the same.

Inside you'll see the compiled object files ".o" which contains the architecture compiled code and debug symbols, and the package definition file (__.PKGDEF) which contains the package metadata.